# CC_DEGRESS_TO_RADIANS error

Tags: objective-c, xcode4, cocos2d-iphone

I've got an error when I build project.

The error is this.

```
CC_DEGREES_TO_RADIANS was not declared in this scope.
```

At the beginning of code, I inserted a row

```
#include "cocos2d.h"
```

What's the matter?
Why this error occured?

Also when I clicked the line " #include 'cocos2d.h' "
I must get into the cocos2d.h, but no result happen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably have a typo. It might be `CC_DEGREES_TO_RADIANS`.

**[EDIT]**
Apparently this identifier seems to be from custom code, but forunately can be easily defined:

```
#define CC_DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(__ANGLE__) ((__ANGLE__) * 0.01745329252f)
```

Comment: I've changed. But no change appear.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include "cocos2d.h"
```

Should be

```
#import "cocos2d.h"
```

Comment: Do you have all the cocos2d files added to your project? Did you start from the cocos2d template?

Comment: I always create project based on cocos.

Comment: Your import statement must be in the wrong place, then, as everything should be working. Can you post more code?